# Best way to document REST APIs in (go) source?

Tags: documentation-generator, rest, go

I am working on a REST API implemented in go.
I have already [wrestled with godoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101458/what-are-the-syntactic-and-semantic-rules-for-meaningful-comments-in-go?noredirect=1#comment93103058_53101458)

Colleagues have started using [apidoc.js](http://apidocjs.com/) but I have found in lacking in several areas. For example I don't even know [how to insert a simple comment](https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc/issues/761).

As someone used to Doxygen, I find godoc and apidoc.js to be very limiting.

[swagger](https://swagger.io/) looks like it might be a better option but there seem to be several possibly competing or superseded ways of writing comments.
For example:
 https://goswagger.io/use/spec/route.html

Has magic comments starting with "swagger:" like

```
// swagger:route GET /pets pets users listPets
```

While https://github.com/swaggo/echo-swagger uses comments prefixed with an @ like:

```
// @title Swagger Example API
// @version 1.0
```

echo-swagger appeals because I have also inherited a preference to use labstack/echo from the same colleagues

[Swaggo](https://github.com/swaggo/swag#general-api-info) also uses @ prefixed comments but I'm not sure its the same format:

```
// @Param enumstring query string false "string enums" Enums(A, B, C)
```

I recall there was a competitor to swagger. Googling I only came up with openAPI. It seems swagger2.0 == openAPI 2.0 so I guess they merged. Then I discovered openAPI 3.0 exists and go-swagger [doens't yet support it](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/1122)

There also seem to be [RAML and API blueprint](https://nordicapis.com/top-specification-formats-for-rest-apis/) too.

I'm leaning towards swagger.io as its documentation seems more complete.
What do typical gophers (or engineers in other languages) prefer and why?

There is [another question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/29925/which-tool-would-you-use-for-producing-rest-api-docs-from-java-code) which asks this for Java and ironically gives the answer Doxygen. I am not aware of any good examples of REST documentation in Doxygen though. I'm not sure it would be a good fit outside of its comfort zone. It [doesn't officially support go yet](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5143)

Comment: I'm not 100% clear if I would be better of asking this on softwareengineering or here but it is basically a recommendation question.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you think REST API documentation should look like?

Comment: That is a whole other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937379/example-of-a-well-documented-restful-service - with some useful answers.

Comment: And what  a great question it is too (ah! for the days when we could about tools - and books - and even use the word "best" - on S.O). Did you check out [REST Tool](http://tombenke.github.io/rest-tool/index.html)? If you do get an answer, please post it here and accept it, as that would be very useful to others in future. Thanks

Comment: I'm leaning towards go-swagger so far but more as a schilling point than for any technical reason.